# iOS - PassBook Automatic Updates

Tags: ios, passbook

I created a pass file and added in the wallet. I was wondering what am I missing that will show the Automatic updates option at the back of the pass ? 
Like in this image : https://dxjl3qy52c1o9.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/22080644/ios-apple-wallet-share-526x1024.png

Back of my pass looks like this Image : 
https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/iphone6-ios9-wallet-pass-auto-updates-inshell.jpg

I added the pass by two ways, one was manually by sending via email and other was adding pass file in the xcode bundle resources and fetching from there via code and adding using Passkit framework as mentioned in this tutorial: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-6-tutorial-integrating-passbook-into-your-applications

Do I need to have a server integrated to make that option show up ? As I read something of the sort in the apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988) and some other answers.

I am not trying to update the pass, I was just wondering for learning purpose why is that option is not shown at back of my own pass. If some one can clarfiy this, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to have a webServiceURL and authenticationToken in your pass.json to make the option appear.

For updates to work then you will need to implement the web service protocol on your server.

Comment: Hey, I have a follow up question on this topic. If you could help me with that also, I would be grateful.

Comment: The documentation is pretty straightforward and there is more than enough information on StackOverflow already regarding implementing this service.  If you try and get stuck then post another question.

Comment: I feel like the question I have is not big enough to be asked as a proper question on the stackoverflow. And I am not having a problem with implementing the webservice. Here is the question : Can I automatically update the pass I added manually e.g. via sending and downloading from an email ? Ofcourse I can resend an email and update it from there. I am almost certain that the answer is No. But I just want to make sure by getting an expert's opinion.

Comment: Yes - as long as the passTypeID and serial are the same as the original pass, then installing a new pass from web or email will overwrite the existing pass.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did not phrase my question properly, my bad. What I meant was using webserivces, not via sending through email. Like how automatic updates are supposed to work. Or maybe I did not understood your answer properly.

Comment: Yes you can. You can try are services at PassKit.com if you want to see this working before you start developing.

Comment: Or try mystic8ball.com for an example from our SDK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110128/discussion-between-abdul91-and-passkit).